# unitary test laravel and php

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-testing

it´s my first time that I´m doing the unitary test in PHP and laravel and I have this problem:

```
Tests\Vocces\Company\Routes\CreateNewCompanyRouteTest > post create new company route
  Expected status code 201 but received 404.
  Failed asserting that 201 is identical to 404.
```

i think that my problem it´s in route, but i don´t know. My API routes it´s:

```
Route::post('/company', [App\Http\Controllers\Api\Company\PostCreateCompanyController::class, '__invoke']);
Route::resource('company', CompanyController::class);
```

i think that my test call to `/company` route and this call to this function:

```
public function __invoke(CreateCompanyRequest $request, CompanyCreator $service)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
            $company = $service->handle(Str::uuid(), $request->name);
            DB::commit();
            return response($company, 201);
        } catch (\Throwable $error) {
            DB::rollback();
            throw $error;
        }
    }
```

my test:

```
class CreateNewCompanyRouteTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @group route
     * @group access-interface
     * @test
     */
    public function postCreateNewCompanyRoute()
    {
        /**
         * Preparing
         */
        $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();
        $testCompany = [
            'name'   => $faker->name,
            'status' => 'inactive',
        ];

        /**
         * Actions
         */
        $response = $this->json('POST', '/api/company', [
            'name' => $testCompany['name'],
        ]);

        /**
         * Asserts
         */
        $response->assertStatus(201)
            ->assertJsonFragment($testCompany);
    }
}
```

my application has 9 tests I passed 8 but I don´t know what it´s my problem. I hope anybody can help me.

Sorry for my English

**UPDATE:**

```
| Domain | Method    | URI                      | Name              | Action                                                                 | Middleware |
+--------+-----------+--------------------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                        | home              | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web        |
|        | POST      | api/company              |                   | App\Http\Controllers\Api\Company\PostCreateCompanyController@__invoke  | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/company/index        | company.index     | App\Http\Controllers\Api\Company\CompanyController@index               | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/company/{id}/edit    | company.edit      | App\Http\Controllers\Api\Company\CompanyController@edit                | api        |
|        | PUT       | api/company/{id}/update  | company.update    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\Company\CompanyController@update              | api        |
|        | POST      | companies                | companies.store   | App\Http\Controllers\CompanyController@store                           | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | companies                | companies.index   | App\Http\Controllers\CompanyController@index                           | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | companies/create         | companies.create  | App\Http\Controllers\CompanyController@create                          | web        |
|        | DELETE    | companies/{company}      | companies.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\CompanyController@destroy                         | web        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | companies/{company}      | companies.update  | App\Http\Controllers\CompanyController@update                          | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | companies/{company}      | companies.show    | App\Http\Controllers\CompanyController@show                            | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | companies/{company}/edit | companies.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\CompanyController@edit                            | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | home                     | home              | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@home                               | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | login                    | login             | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web        |
|        |           |                          |                   |                                                                        | guest      |
|        | POST      | login                    |                   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web        |
|        |           |                          |                   |                                                                        | guest      |
|        | POST      | logout                   | logout            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web        |
|        | POST      | password/confirm         |                   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@confirm            | web        |
|        |           |                          |                   |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/confirm         | password.confirm  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@showConfirmForm    | web        |
|        |           |                          |                   |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | POST      | password/email           | password.email    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web        |
|        | POST      | password/reset           | password.update   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset           | password.request  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset/{token}   | password.reset    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web        |
|        | POST      | register                 |                   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web        |
|        |           |                          |                   |                                                                        | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD  | register                 | register          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web        |
|        |           |                          |                   |                                                                        | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users                    | users.index       | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index                              | web        |
|        | POST      | users                    | users.store       | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@store                              | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users/create             | users.create      | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@create                             | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users/{user}             | users.show        | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@show                               | web        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | users/{user}             | users.update      | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@update                             | web        |
|        | DELETE    | users/{user}             | users.destroy     | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@destroy                            | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users/{user}/edit        | users.edit        | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@edit                               | web        |
+--------+-----------+--------------------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: Looks like there is no `/api/company` route defined, only `/company`

Comment: @brombeer if i declare it in api.php same problem. I have route in web.php and api.php

Comment: Right, my fault, I missed your "_My API routes..._". Does it show up in `php artisan route:list`? Might be your `Route::resource(...)` overwrites your previous/actual route

Comment: @brombeer i updated my question with all my routes

Comment: @brombeer i deleted my rereource routes and create route manually. all my app it´s ok, but this test not run. in my route list appear this route type post

Comment: In your `->json` call, remove the leading slash: `$this->json('POST', 'api/company',...)`